# Updated Indy - Getting error related to IPPeerClient and IPPeerServer

Tags: indy, indy10, delphi-10-seattle

I've been practicing updating Indy on a VM and I've gotten far enough to compile some of my projects but not all.

First of all I'm Delphi Seattle, updated to Indy 10.6.2 following the instructions [here](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-bmimleug-bq.html)

In my client projects that use Indy, there is IPPeerClient in the Uses clause. This is causing the error "Unit IPPeerClient was compiled with a different version of IdTCPConnection.TidTCPConnection". I can remove the Use statement and they seem to be working (so far, the ones I've tested).

But for my server projects (datasnap and others), if I try to remove IPPeerServer, it gets added back in automatically and I'm stuck.

Comment: Embarcadero's technologies that use Indy internally use a private copy that is not supposed to be affected by users installing/updating their own copy of Indy.  If you are updating your own copy of Indy and DataSnap then breaks, then there is a setup problem somewhere. But, that being said, installing a new Indy does have some known effects on Embarcadero packages, see [Indy's installation notes](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) for details.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I used the Indy's installation notes to help guide the process, and I'm glad for them. I'm just surprised since the only mention of DataSnap is XE->XE2 and I'm well past those versions. This particular DataSnap project was built in XE3 and ported to Seattle later. Maybe that's why it won't compile?

Comment: Just finished building a fresh DataSnap project (Stand alone and/or ISAPI) in Seattle. When saving it always adds IPPeerServer to the Uses clause. Don't think it had anything to do with porting from XE3.